# Read csv where headers are inside the datacells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to import a csv in Python with the following format:

```
with open('categories.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

```
['id', 'categories']
['2', 'related-1;request-0;offer-0;aid_related-0;medical_help-0;medical_products-0;search_and_rescue-0;security-0;military-0;child_alone-0;water-0;food-0;shelter-0;clothing-0;money-0;missing_people-0;refugees-0;death-0;other_aid-0;infrastructure_related-0;transport-0;buildings-0;electricity-0;tools-0;hospitals-0;shops-0;aid_centers-0;other_infrastructure-0;weather_related-0;floods-0;storm-0;fire-0;earthquake-0;cold-0;other_weather-0;direct_report-0']
['7', 'related-1;request-0;offer-0;aid_related-1;medical_help-0;medical_products-0;search_and_rescue-0;security-0;military-0;child_alone-0;water-0;food-0;shelter-0;clothing-0;money-0;missing_people-0;refugees-0;death-0;other_aid-1;infrastructure_related-0;transport-0;buildings-0;electricity-0;tools-0;hospitals-0;shops-0;aid_centers-0;other_infrastructure-0;weather_related-1;floods-0;storm-1;fire-0;earthquake-0;cold-0;other_weather-0;direct_report-0']
```

In the end, the dataframe should look like this:

```
ID related request  ...
 2       1       0  ...
 7       1       0  ...
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your CSV file, @Anka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using ***pandas***:

```
import pandas

df = pd.read_csv('./text.csv')
# get and expand columns
columns = [i.split('-')[0] for i in df['categories'].str.split(';')[0]]
df[columns] = df['categories'].str.split(';', expand=True)
# drop categories column
df.drop('categories', axis=1, inplace=True)
# get value for each column
for column in columns:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x : x.split('-')[1])
print(df)
```

[image]